# How to pass a table join to my view in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to C# and asp.net and mvc. I am trying to figure out how to pass my data from my controller to my view. I got it working with one table, but I need more info.

My controller

```
namespace OpenCustomerOrders.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {

        OrderContext db = new OrderContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var query = (from h in db.oeordhdr_sql
                         join l in db.oeordlin_sql
                         on h.ord_no equals l.ord_no
                         select new
                         {
                             h.ord_no,
                             h.ship_via_cd,
                             h.bill_to_name,
                             l.item_no,
                             l.qty_ordered,
                             l.item_desc_1,
                         }).ToList();


            return View(query);
        }
    }
}
```

My view right now looks like

```
@model IEnumerable<OpenCustomerOrders.oeordhdr_sql>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <th>Bill to Name</th>

 <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ord_no)
        </td>
```

Comment: create a viewmodel class, instead of using Model class directly in view

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on your return line, and then inspect what `query` contains. Is it what you expect? That might point you in the right direction. As it stands, not sure how what you're getting is different from what you're expecting.

Comment: You query is creating a collection of anonymous objects (not a collection of `oeordhdr_sql` expected by you view. You need to create a view model containing the properties you need and project the query to that view model - `select new MyViewModel { .... }` and change the view to `@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a ViewModel here and add properties in it which are needed to be displayed on the view, which would look like:

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{

  public int ord_no { get;set; }
  public int item_no { get;set; }
  // other properties needed
  .................
  .................                       
}
```

and then in your linq query you would project with that class instance like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var query = (from h in db.oeordhdr_sql
                  join l in db.oeordlin_sql
                  on h.ord_no equals l.ord_no
                  select new OrdersViewModel
                  {
                      ord_no = h.ord_no,
                      .........
                      .........
                      item_no = l.item_no
                  }).ToList();


     return View(query);
}
```

and now in View change the model to new viewmodel :

```
@model IEnumerable<OpenCustomerOrders.OrdersViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 <th>Bill to Name</th>

 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ord_no)</td>
```